ROS - Incresed delay when using "Exact Time Synchronization" for camera streams
We have a multiple camera system (Realsense D435) setup used in a ROS environment.
We're using Ubuntu 22.04 and ROS Noetic.
The problem we're seeing is that the delay of each image is increased by 20ms once we start a node that's using the sync policy ExactTime, that will try to synchronize the color stream with a second topic in time.
message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime

Prior to starting the node Im checking the delay of the the camera stream by:
rostopic delay /camera4/color/image_raw

And the the delay is around 98ms.
However, once the node has started, and I'm checking the delay with the same command, the delay have instead increased to 119ms.
Why is this?
